# run cronjob for data.php in helper?

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

Want to run a function that placed in helper(Data.php) with cronjob every minute in my extension, is this possible?

function will update status of custom shipping that come from webservice

Answer (score 2):

[Implement your own cronjob](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

and inside your model and method just call: `Mage::helper('yourmodule')->function()`

And I'm sure it is somehow possible to instantiate a helper instead of a model, but I don't think it is worth the time to check this out.

Comment: yes, it seems is better use observer for cronjob and now switch to observer but have another problem here, please see : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18140/update-database-column-for-every-row-how

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part of code how magento parses `<model>` of cronjob:

```
if (!preg_match(self::REGEX_RUN_MODEL, (string)$runConfig->model, $run)) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Invalid model/method definition, expecting "model/class::method".'));
}
if (!($model = Mage::getModel($run[1])) || !method_exists($model, $run[2])) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Invalid callback: %s::%s does not exist', $run[1], $run[2]));
}
```

In Magento there is a trick that you can load even helper with `Mage::getModel` if you specify full class name and not Magento alias like this:

```
Mage::getModel('Namespace_Module_Helper_Data')
```

But in case of cron jobs the content of `<model>` is parsed by `self::REGEX_RUN_MODEL`:

```
#^([a-z0-9_]+/[a-z0-9_]+)::([a-z0-9_]+)$#i
```

Which does not allow to use capitalized letters.

So as a conclusion you cannot use anything else inside `<model>` tag except magento models aliases. You cannot even use full class name as it is possible with observers.

Comment: I'm sorry you are wrong. the i at the end makes it case insensitive. But because of the / in the regex, the magento syntax is forced (edited from "wow, thanks good to know to you are wrong, to I'm wrong, you are right :D)

Comment: You are totally right about the "i" in regex. Shame to me:(.

Comment: As I said, the first time I didn't see it, then I saw it... then I recognized the `/` :D You are on a good way to become perfect - like me (being on the way, not being perfect ;-))